# Publishing Chrome Extension directly from Github

Tags: google-chrome, github, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have my chrome extension (the one's I authored) hosted on Google Chrome store. I did create a developer account (5$ one).

I'd like to link my chrome extension to it's github repository and automatically update it every-time I update the code instead of manually zipping it and uploading the zip file. Is there a way to do that? I couldn't find anything here https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/publish/

There is a self hosting section but I don't think that helps with what I'm trying to. Has anyone figured out an automatic deployment from github to chrome store?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/using_webstore_api/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider using a [GitHub Action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions), like for instance [Chrome Extension upload & publish](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/chrome-extension-upload-publish)

That way, the zip/upload process will be automated.

Example:

```
uses: Klemensas/chrome-extension-upload-action@$VERSION
with:
  refresh-token: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  client-id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  client-secret: ${{ secrets.CHROME_EXTENSION_SECRET }}
  file-name: './extension.zip'
  app-id: 'xzc12xzc21cx23'
  publish: true
```

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71813185/publishing-chrome-extension-directly-from-github/71813642?noredirect=1#comment126906418_71813642) by [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom), make sure to set the `client-secret` value as a **[GitHub Secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets)**, as [shown here](https://github.com/Azure/actions-workflow-samples/blob/master/assets/create-secrets-for-GitHub-workflows.md).
In the example above, I reference a secret named '`CHROME_EXTENSION_SECRET`' that you must define first in your GitHub repository which has the sources of your extension:

```
${{ secrets.CHROME_EXTENSION_SECRET }}
```

[image: https://github.com/Azure/actions-workflow-samples/raw/master/assets/images/Add-secret-name-value.png]

Comment: @wOxxOm Good point. I have edited the answer to clearly reference a secret in the parameters of that GitHub Action.